# Android: Is there an easier way to call specific integers in an if else statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, int

Currently this is what my if/else statement looks like:

```
if (x ==1 || x == 4 || x == 7 || x == 10 || x == 13 || x == 16, etc...) { }
```

Is there an easier way to clean this up? The list goes up to 50 so it's taking up a bunch of space. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `if((x % 3) == 1)`?

Comment: Shove them all in a `HashSet` and use `contains`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they always goes up by 3 then you could do

```
if(x < 50 && x % 3 == 1)
```

the modulo return the remaining of a division.

I believe that the highest possible value will be 49 even if you said that it goes up to 50 as you confirmed that it always go up by 3.

Else if you are wondering if there is such a thing like `x in (1,2,3)` in java, then no there isn't.

Comment: Yes, the entire list goes up by three. Will this work for the entire list if it keeps following this pattern?

Comment: OP said the list goes up to 50.  Your list goes up to about 2 billion.  So this condition isn't equivalent to what the OP specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ArrayList and add all your values to it.
Then check if the arraylist contains "x"

Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
...
if(list.contains(x)){/*do stuff*/}
```

Comment: Faster to use a `Set` than a `List` for this kind of thing.  But this is currently the only really good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

A [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is an alternative that would make your code much more readable.

```
switch (number) {
            case 1:  number = 1;
            case 2:  number = 4;
            case 3:  number = 7;
            ...
            case n: number = n;
                     doSomething();
                     break;
            default: number = 0;
                     break;
}
```

However, if your integers always incremenst by three, you could implement a `modulo`, which would reduce the amount of code drastically.

```
if (x % 3 == 1) {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: In this case a switch statement makes it more "unreadable", all those breaks and cases, whats wrong with if (x==2) doSomething(); :)

Comment: The asker's if method was TONS of OR operations in the if statement. I guess you could accomplish the same with separate if-else if-else statements,but similarly the switch handles one case at a time.

Comment: Well in the OP case, the switch statement is really useless since you are calling the same method to each cases.

Comment: @domi, I guess you are right. I've updated the answer to not have to break out of everything case, and to use the doSomething() method once.

Answer (score 0):

This for-loop will print out similar values between 1 and 49:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x += 3) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Maybe you can use similar logic in your `if` statement.